# probability and distributions 3

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Why for some distributions is $P(X\geq 50)=1-P(X \leq 49)$.
However, for some other questions, I have seen examples where $P(X\geq 50)=1-P(X\leq 50)$.
Has it got something to do with discrete and continuous distributions being different?

Comment: Yes this comes from the fact that $\int_{a}^{a} f =0$

Comment: ok so for all continuous distributions P(X>=x)=1-P(X<=x-1)

Comment: Nope, $P(X \ge x) = 1- P(X \le x)$, if $X$ is a continuous random variable.

Comment: @zee: what you wrote applies to the discrete distribution

Answer (score 0):

For a continuous random variable $X$ it holds
$$ \mathbb{P} (X \le x) = \mathbb{P} (X \lt x)$$
since, assuming that $X$ admits a probability density function $f_X$,
$$ \mathbb{P} (X=x) = \int_x^x f_X(x) \,dx = 0, $$
(i.e., a point is a $0$ measure set). Hence, for continuous random variables,
$$ \mathbb{P} (X \ge x) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X < x) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X\le x). $$

For a discrete random variable $X$ in general this is not true, indeed, $\mathbb{P}(X=x) \ne 0$ (in general) and
$$ \mathbb{P} (X\le x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^x \mathbb{P}(X=k) = \mathbb{P}(X=x) + \sum_{k=-\infty}^{x-1} \mathbb{P}(X=k) = \mathbb{P}(X=x) + \mathbb{P}(X < x),$$
and, hence,
$$ \mathbb{P}(X\ge x) = 1 -\mathbb{P}(X<x) = 1 - \bigl( \mathbb{P}(X\le x) - \mathbb{P}(X=x) \bigr). $$